# error in makeOffer() --- (node steam-tradeoffers)

Tags: node.js, bots, steam

I am aware that this problem was discussed before but I have not notice a solution yet.
I tried trading with friends using their steamID64, but when I unfriended them and used their steamID64 and their trade url I keep getting the following error. I am using Alex7Kom's steam-tradeoffer module.

[image]

The code I use :

```
offers.makeOffer({
    partnerSteamId: '76561198239572270',
    accessToken: 'https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=279306542&token=2RRFVBfM',
    itemsFromMe: [ { appid: 730, contextid: 2, amount: 1, assetid: item.id } ],
    itemsFromThem: [],
    message: 'To je avtomatsko! Lahko tut uzames.'
}, function(err, response) {
    if(err){ throw err; } console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Please include a text version of the your error message and use the editor tools to format it. Off-site resources like those images often disappear, making the question useless in the future.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is returning an error which, in turn, causes your code `throw err` to be triggered.

The most likely culprit is your access token:

```
accessToken: 'https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=279306542&token=2RRFVBfM',
```

You've got an entire URL which seems like a strange access token, they're usually a random set of characters. Further confirming this, the [`makeOffer()`](https://github.com/Alex7Kom/node-steam-tradeoffers#makeofferoptions-callback) function says

> accessToken (optional) is a token from the public Trade URL of the partner.

Based on this documentation, it seems to indicate the token is *in* the URL, not the URL itself. Given that the URL you're using has `token=2RRFVBfM` in it, you probably only need to have that token value in your parameters.

```
accessToken: '2RRFVBfM',
```